# "wait me" or "wait for me"?

Tags: sentence-choice

I am interested to know which is the right way to say:

> *wait me?*

Or

> *wait for me?*

I was debating over this with my girlfriend, and she claims that we can also say *"wait me"*. Is she right?

Comment: I haven't head "wait me" until I met this question.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike in languages such as Spanish ("Por favor, espéreme.") in English one must say "Please wait for me."

Comment: The "please" is optional. (In terms of grammar, anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

I've searched the American Corpus of Contemporary English and British National Corpus and only the COCA found some matches, more precisely: three. However, "wait me" was part of the phrasal verb "to wait out something".

So I guess it is non-existent or close to being non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, "wait me" is not used by the English speaking people. They use "wait for" something. Wait me is rather a translation from the French language:"Attendez- moi".